# How to delete from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have an html form like so:

```
<form method="post" action="input.php">
<label for="name">NAME</label>
<input type="text" name="name" size="20">
<label for="address">ADDIE</label>
<input type="text" name="address" size="40">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
```

and I have:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","formuser","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("formpractice") or die(mysql_error());


$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];


$query = "INSERT INTO Users(name, address) VALUES ('$name', '$address')";

$qresult = mysql_query($query);

if ($qresult) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Failed to submit";
}

?>
```

I'm trying this:

```
<form method="post" action="input.php">
<label for="name">NAME</label>
<input type="text" name="name" size="20">
<label for="address">ADDIE</label>
<input type="text" name="address" size="40">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
// Here is where I get trouble. How do I get this button to execute a delete statement?
<input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="input.php">
<label for="name">NAME</label>
<input type="text" name="name" size="20">
<label for="address">ADDIE</label>
<input type="text" name="address" size="40">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
// Here is where I get trouble. How do I get this button to execute a delete statement?
<input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete">
```

Whatever you put in "name" is what will get sent in the method used for the form (in this case, POST); which you will find in the global variable $_POST. In order to get that button to "delete", you need to have, somewhere (in this case, it would be on the .php file that is metnioned in the "action" attribute of your forgm tag), the php code that does the deleting using the information that you have passed along through the form (name and address).

If you were going to keep the same form, meaning you will be using two submit buttons, then your php code must, somehow, figure out what action you want it to carry out (input or delete), that´s where you will use the name attribute of the input tag.

```
<?php
     if($_POST['Delete']{ 
         //connect to database, issue query, close database
     }

     if($_POST['submit']{
           //the code you had for sending the data
     }
?>
```

I strongly recommend the book Head First PHP and MySQL for learning!

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="something.php" method=post">
Name: <input type=text name="name">
Price: <input type=text name="othername">
<input type=submit value="remove this from the database on the web server">
</form>
```

Add this php:

```
<?=
$name=$_POST['name'];
$price=$_POST['price'];

$sql = "Delete * from (whatever) VALUES ('$name','$othername')";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
?>
```